# Motion of objects (beginner)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have begun physics and we are seeing systems of reference as an introduction.Now I have a small exercise which I'm not sure of, I would need you to check if it's correct or not.

There are two cyclists A and B. Suppose that you take place on a sidewalk and look at them pass. They move to the right and to a constant speed.

What trajectory do you associate to the cyclists ? Rectilinear (so, one "x" axis.)

What answer would the cyclist A give if we asked her to determine the trajectory of cyclist B ? Rectilinear also.

Represent the trajectory of the reflector placed in the front wheel of cyclist B, such that you would see her from the sidewalk.

[image]

The curves are halfs of a circle and I considered that the reflector began at half the height of the wheel.( so there's the highest point, middle point and the case where the reflector "touches" the ground.)

Comment: The curves traced out by the reflectors do not have semi-circlular parts. The curve is called a cycloid. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks So are the other two correct or not ?

Comment: Yes, though I'd recommend being more specific: the motion is *uniformly* rectilinear.